# Comparing confidence intervals around differences?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, group-differences

Consider the following hypothetical scenario:
Let variable $x$ be normally distributed with $x \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. We sample two populations A and B in one-go, i.e., within the same study, and calculate the point estimate for the difference between the means of A and B as well as its 95% confidence interval (for the sake of simplicity, using a t-test, with balanced samples).

My question is, if this is repeated in another region in a different study, and measures the same variables in the same way, the point estimate for difference between means of A and B + 95% CI is calculated:

1. Are these between-study intervals comparable?
2. What if we convert the difference in means to a standardized effect size, i.e., Cohen's d?
3. Can you infer anything by comparing the difference in mean's confidence intervals between these two studies?

I can see that this would require meta-analytical procedures, but I'm unsure if this simple exercise is biased and wrong.